# Allow Drop Downs in an SSRS Report (2008) to accept text as an input

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Okay, so I have an SSRS report that has a parameter with available values from a query. All of this works fine, but I would like the user to be able to select multiple items using: "SomeText%" which will retrieve all like: SomeText12, SomeTextHeyThere etc. The sql for this is all set up, but once you set the parameter to get values from a query in visual studio, you don't have the option to enter in text as well. This seems like it should be a common feature. Does anyone know how to add it so that the user can enter text and select from the drop down at the same time? I can create 2 parameters to do this, but that is just clunky.
Thanks!

Comment: You'll probably have to have that as a seperate input text box.  Then in the query tell it to look at what's in the drop down OR where text field LIKE '%blabla%'

Comment: That is a solution that works and is what I mentioned above. You don't think there is any way to avoid using two inputs?

Comment: No. SSRS Parameters are exactly as you described "just clunky". The functionality hasnt been improved in any meaningful way since V1 back in 2003.  There are a few Suggestions on Connect which you could upvote, FWIW ...